# How to concatenate properties of an element of type Object in C #

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, concatenation

I want to concatenate an ID with the name of a product as shown in the following image

[image: screenshot]

The problem is that the property that I load into the list is of type Object, here my data structure

```
public class FabricanteFormResponse
{    
      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "results")]
       public FabricanteForm Results { get; set; }
}

public class FabricanteForm
{
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "columns")]
     public List<int> Columns { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sqs")]
     public List<List<Sqs>> Sqs { get; set; }
}

public class Sqs
{
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "field")]
      public string Field { get; set;}

     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "column")]
      public int Column { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
      public Object Value { get; set; }

}
```

The logic is thus, when the column takes the value 2 it is a product and when the column takes the value 1 it is the ID.

[image: POSTMAN]

then when I open my ViewModel I create an ObservableCollection of Sqs and a method LoadSubstances () that loads the list of this object of type Object when the column is 2 with LINQ

```
#region Constructor
public ResultadosHDSViewModel()
 {  
    Sqss = new ObservableCollection<Sqs>();

    LoadSustancias();
 }
#endregion


#region Metodos           
 public async void LoadSustancias()
 {          
      var mainViewModel = MainViewModel.GetInstance();

    var sustancias = mainViewModel.FabricanteForm.Results.Sqs.Select(c => c.Where(v => v.Column == 2)
                        .Select(u => u).ToList()).ToList();

      Sqss.Clear();

      foreach (var item in sustancias)
      {
         foreach (var itemSqs in item)
         {
             if (itemSqs.Column == 2)
             {
               Sqss.Add(itemSqs);
              }
          }
      }         
}
#endregion
```

In my Vista I occupy the following bindings

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Sqss}"
                  SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                         Padding="16,0,0,0">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Value}" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                       FontSize="Small" 
                                       TextColor="{StaticResource das.color.texto}"
                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

As occupying the data structure previously presented can I concatenate the ID together with the Product Name? Can I do it from my LoadSubstance Method? should I create a new property?

any help for me?

Answer (score 0):

From the `Sqs` list of lists get the relevant item

```
List<Sqs> item = Sqs[i];
string formattedString = $"({item[0].Value}) {item[1].Value}";
                                                    // e.g. "(2) 10-31 LIMPIADOR DE CONTACTOS"
```

assuming that id and product are always the two first items.

---

But it would be much easier if you created a `Product` class and converted the raw Json properties list into a products list

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
    }

    public Product(List<Sqs> properties)
    {
        Id = (int)properties[0].Value;
        Name = (string)properties[1].Value;
        Manufacturer = (string)properties[2].Value;
        Keywords = (string)properties[3].Value;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Keywords { get; set; }

    public string ProductText => $"({Id}) {Name}";

    public override string ToString() => ProductText;
}
```

This class has a property `ProductText` and overrides `ToString` to let it produce your formatted string as desired.

Replace `Sqss` by `Products`

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Then you can simply create a products list in `LoadSustancias()` with

```
Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(mainViewModel.FabricanteForm.Results.Sqs
    .Select(props => new Product(props))
);
```

Now you can bind your `ListView` to a `Products` list and bind the label to `<Label Text="{Binding ProductText}" ...`.

Comment: Would you suggest putting this in the Sqs.CS class? keep the Binding in view? or should I merge the formated string property? @Oliver

Comment: The problem is that the information comes from 2 different `Sqs` objects, so you cannot simply make it a property. But you could add it as static method to the class.

Comment: when you add your method to the class Sqs.CS I get these errors: "The name 'does not exist in the current context" ------ "A field initializer can not reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Sqs.item' "

Comment: You cannot add this to `Sqs` as you need a `List<Sqs>`. In my example `Sqs` is of type `List<List<Sqs>>`. The code would go into `LoadSustancias` I think.

Comment: I am trying to implement your response, but if you do not tell me where it is very difficult for me